# Execute "chown -R www-data:www-data /path" from laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04

Is there a way to execute the command `chown -R www-data:www-data /path` from a laravel controller?

Comment: This command requires execution as root user. So the common answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

plz try this, it`s work for me

```
1.cd {laravel_root}
2.chmod 777 -R storage
3.chown -R www-data:www-data storage
```

Comment: Well this is completely off topic. I know how to do this. I was asking if there is a way to execute a command such as this one from the controller.

Comment: plz, use this link https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html @Emmanuel-Ab

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command that does that using Symfony Process and then call that command from your Controller.

This is how it would look like, first create the command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands

use App;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
[...]

class YourCommand extends Command
{
  [...]

  public function handle()
  {
    $process = new Process("chown -R www-data:www-data /path");
    $process->run();
    return true;
  }
}
```

And then in your controller just call your Artisan command:

```
$result = Artisan::call("yourcommand");
```

Hope this helped!